# gollum-auth, for newbies

Tags: gollum-wiki

I am a non-Ruby person looking for some basic help.

I am thinking gollum is an easy way to do a personal wiki, I love that it is backed by simple files, sitting in git. Following the *simple* instructions I have it working!

Very cool.

But I would like to put some security around it, so I could put it on the internet and keep uninvited people out. For this gollum-auth looks like the ticket. And, another question ([How to configure Gollum-wiki to allow basic authentication and to use the username for the git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690778/how-to-configure-gollum-wiki-to-allow-basic-authentication-and-to-use-the-userna/53299428#53299428) answer by Björn Albers https://stackoverflow.com/users/2786269/bj%c3%b6rn-albers) looks like what I want, but I need some basic help understanding the answer:

- What does "load it before gollum" mean?
- Where do I put a config.ru?

Thanks.

-kb